# django notification templates

Tags: django

Hi everyone
I am currently using django notification and I realize there are 5 views available. 
I was wondering whether there are any examples on the templates for these views.

Is this app dead? Why are there so few docs?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat late, but perhaps useful for other people. There are examples for the various views in pinax, so for instance for notice_settings.html:

https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/themes/default/templates/notification/notice_settings.html

UPDATE: Since Pinax removed their themes, the last checkin with templates can still be found at:
https://github.com/pinax/pinax/tree/7f5c31fbcf455767dc7bc79a53be39038e00786f/pinax/themes/default/templates/notification

Answer (score 0):

The app doesn't seem to be dead, the last modification was in September. It is not highly maintained either, though.

I don't know if you've seen [usage.txt](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/blob/master/docs/usage.txt), but it seems that this one explains how the app works. I've seen worse documented apps.